# How to properly label colliding labels in QGIS 3.x

Tags: qgis-3, labeling

Is there a way to properly show the labels when "Show all labels for this layer (including colliding labels)" is selected from label properties? I was looking for adding callout lines for the labels but I think it requires the labels to be manually displaced. As there's more than 1000 points it will be too time consuming to do this. Is there an easier way to do this?

[image: Colliding labels]

It should be sufficient if the points are clustered and each point in that cluster can be labelled as shown below.

[image: Labeling a cluster of points]

Comment: Sometimes you just need a different approach. Looking at that cluster at the bottom of the image, even if the labels were perfectly placed with callout lines, would it even be legible?

Comment: Absolutely agree with you @TeddyTedTed. Can you suggest a better approach?

Comment: What other approaches have you considered? Have you looked at the 16 other questions on this site about "qgis colliding labels"?

Comment: Hmmm. Well, It is possible to make a cluster of the points. But then I also want to show the labels separately along with the number of points in the cluster. I am adding a picture in the question.